# Why can I not see the whole window?

Tags: 12.04, resolution, display, button, ideapad

I have the following problem:
my Lenovo ideapad S10e runs on Ubuntu 12.04 and everytime I open a window it doesn' show it entirely. Meaning: the buttons on the bottom are out of the displays range (I hope I make myself clear...). I usually solve this problem by resizing the window and then  move it up but with the system windows that doesn't work which means I cannot hit the APPLY button or such.
I read through zillions of posts concerning Ubuntu but couldn't find a solution.
What could be the problem?
The resolution (which can't be changed)?
The netbooks graphic card or display driver?
I am stumped...

Answer (score 1):

I just resolved the problem
Setting>> Appearance>> Fonts>> then change the font size down to 9 or until you can see the buttons.

Its annoying because you can't make the screen smaller by dragging the top of the window down to make a smaller box, then drag the whole box upwards and scroll down to see the buttons; because it wont or give you the option to. This only occurred when I tried to install a new printer, and in the process menus I couldn't accept or see the buttons to continue the process.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't the resolution be changed?

According to [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SQ_N-mQCmIc), you can change the resolution in Ubuntu 12.04. by going to:

`system--> displays`, selected your monitor, and changing the resolution to a higher one.